# Web services on Jboss ESB

Tags: jbossws

I am looking for a bit of clarity around JBoss ESB and JBoss WS.  I have been asked to build an ESB solution using web services (SOAP/http(s)).

What advantages does using ESB over JBoss WS give me, and how does it fit with the client request - e.g. does the client call the endpoint on the ESB, which is then forward to the Web Service?

Any points would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage is loose coupling of the service and the client. The ESB service could be a proxy to the Web Service. If the Web Service implementation or contract changes, different versions could be exposed on the ESB. The ESB also provides other "mediation" stuff like object transformations and routing.. that way the Web Service can just do it's job, and the ESB service can be used to expose the WS as desired to consumers.

And yes, the client would call the ESB endpoint. I had similiar questions on a project several months back, and found this article to be very useful: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SOA-P43SimpleWebServiceProxy